# How could I download files without an extension using PHP

Tags: php

This is a very weird question that I cannot see asked on this site but how could I just have PHP download a file (say it was a png file) and convert it to having no file extension at all? Before you ask why are you doing this, it's difficult to explain and I would just like to know if it is even possible to do this.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: If it's so difficult to explain, perhaps you shouldn't be doing it. This looks very much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: well say the file is named image.png I want it to only download as image. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
file_put_contents("somepng", fopen("http://url/image.png", 'r'));
```

Comment: How could I incorporate this into downloading an actual file? This seems to just read out the files size in bytes

Comment: You can do it with <?php
$file = file_get_contents('url/file');
file_put_contents('url/file', $file);